# How to alternate rows using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

As I'm fiddling with SwiftUI a bit I'm wondering how to have a horizontal `ScrollView` with 2 alternating rows.

I get the following message when using my example:

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

```
import SwiftUI

struct LabelFilter: View {
    var allLabels = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(allLabels.indices) { index in
                        if (index % 2 == 0) {
                            LabelButton(label: self.allLabels[index]) { }
                        }
                    }
                }.padding()
                HStack {
                    ForEach(allLabels.indices) { index in
                        if (index % 2 == 1) {
                            LabelButton(label: self.allLabels[index]) { }
                        }
                    }
                }.padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this happening, how to fix it and is there a better solution to it?

Answer (score 1):

This code compiles:

```
struct LabelFilter: View {
    var allLabels = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"]

    var evenLabels: [String] {
        stride(from: 0, to: allLabels.count, by: 2).map { allLabels[$0] }
    }

    var oddLabels: [String] {
        stride(from: 1, to: allLabels.count, by: 2).map { allLabels[$0] }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(oddLabels, id: \.self) { label in
                        Text(label)
                    }
                }.padding()
                HStack {
                    ForEach(evenLabels, id: \.self) { label in
                        Text(label)
                    }
                }.padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```